# How to fix error from osm2pgsql importing buildings - Column entry must contain a 'type' string field

Tags: osm2pgsql

I'm trying to follow https://osm2pgsql.org/examples/buildings/ to import building polygons into a Postgres DB.

I have downloaded a pbf file from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html. Specifically, I want to process https://download.geofabrik.de/europe-latest.osm.pbf, but I'm starting out by trying to use the smaller https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/united-kingdom-latest.osm.pbf.

I already have a buildings table with an out of date extract, so I'm trying to publish the new data into a new table name. This is my `buildings.lua`:

```
local buildings = osm2pgsql.define_area_table('buildings_2024_03', {
    -- Define an autoincrementing id column, QGIS likes a unique id on the table
    { column = 'id', sql_type = 'serial', create_only = true },
    { column = 'geom', type = 'polygon', not_null = true },
}, { indexes = {
    -- So we get an index on the id column
    { column = 'id', method = 'btree', unique = true },
    -- If we define any indexes we don't get the default index on the geometry
    -- column, so we add it here.
    { column = 'geom', method = 'gist' }
}})

function osm2pgsql.process_way(object)
    if object.is_closed and object.tags.building then
        buildings:insert({
            geom = object:as_polygon()
        })
    end
end

function osm2pgsql.process_relation(object)
    if object.tags.type == 'multipolygon' and object.tags.building then
        -- From the relation we get multipolygons...
        local mp = object:as_multipolygon()
        -- ...and split them into polygons which we insert into the table
        for geom in mp:geometries() do
            buildings:insert({
                geom = geom
            })
        end
    end
end
```

I'm running the following command (with user/password/host/dbname filled in with real values):

```
> osm2pgsql -O flex -S buildings.lua -d postgresql://user:password
@host:5432/dbname united-kingdom-latest.osm.pbf
2024-03-26 11:10:45  osm2pgsql version 1.4.1
2024-03-26 11:10:45  Database version: 14.10
2024-03-26 11:10:45  PostGIS version: 3.1
2024-03-26 11:10:45  Node-cache: cache=800MB, maxblocks=12800*65536, allocation method=1
2024-03-26 11:10:45  node cache: stored: 0(0.00%), storage efficiency: 0.00% (dense blocks: 0, sparse nodes: 0), hit rate: 0.00%
2024-03-26 11:10:45  ERROR: Error loading lua config: [string "..."]:14: Error in 'define_table': Column entry must contain a 'type' string field.
```

How can I fix this error `Column entry must contain a 'type' string field.`? I don't understand why I'm hitting this error when I'm trying to so closely follow the instructions on https://osm2pgsql.org/examples/buildings/.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of my issue was `osm2pgsql version 1.4.1`

I was running in a debian bullseye container and the osm2pgsql package on this platform is very old and incompatible. I upgraded to debian bookworm and now https://osm2pgsql.org/examples/buildings/ is working as expected.